# Linq to Entities, Operation timeout when I try to use group .. by

Tags: azure, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
        var statList = (from i in _dbContext.Screenshots
                       where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.dateTimeServer.Value) >= startDate && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.dateTimeServer.Value) <= endDate
                       group i by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.dateTimeServer.Value)
                           into g
                           select new ScreenshotStatistic()
                           {
                               Date = g.Key.Value,
                               AllScreenshots = g.Count(),
                               ScreenshotsNoSilent = g.Where(p => p.version.IndexOf("silent") == 0).Count(),
                               ScreenshotsNoSilentWithViews = g.Where(p => p.version.IndexOf("silent") == 0 && p.viewsPage + p.viewsOriginal > 0).Count(),
                               ScreenshotsOnlySilent = g.Where(p => p.version.IndexOf("silent") >= 0).Count(),
                               ScreenshotsOnlySilentWithViews = g.Where(p => p.version.IndexOf("silent") >= 0 && p.viewsPage + p.viewsOriginal > 0).Count(),
                               ScreenshotsOnlyUploadViaSite = g.Where(p => p.version.IndexOf("UPLOAD_VIA_SITE") >= 0).Count(),
                               ScreenshotsOnlyUploadViaSiteWithViews = g.Where(p => p.version.IndexOf("UPLOAD_VIA_SITE") >= 0 && p.viewsPage + p.viewsOriginal > 0).Count()
                           }).ToList();
```

It works carefully for my local database, but I get "Operation timeout" when I try to connect to SQL Azure. As I understand, my request is not optimized. How can I do the request better?

table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Screenshots](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dateTimeClient] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [username] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [filename] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [version] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lang] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dateTimeServer] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Screenshots_dateTimeServer]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [isPublic] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Screenshots_isPublic]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [viewsPage] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Screenshots_viewsPage_1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [viewsThumb] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Screenshots_viewsThumb_1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [viewsOriginal] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Screenshots_viewsOriginal_1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [statusID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Screenshots] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Screenshots]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Screenshots_ScreenshotStatuses] FOREIGN KEY([statusID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ScreenshotStatuses] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Screenshots] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Screenshots_ScreenshotStatuses]
GO
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? and what storage are you using on Azure? e.g. SQL, Table, Blob?

Comment: I can help you improve your query, however I think we can get a better result with more information.

Comment: Could you re-engineer the input of this information so that on save you break out the date and time components and write them to separate properties in the database?  Also, have you ensured you have indexes on the column in Azure? You may also need to change the tier your Azure SQL Database runs at in order to improve performance.

Comment: i want to group by day for statistic. As I said before, I use SQL Azure

Comment: I don't have indexes. Which column should have it?

Comment: I added table structure. Which more data is necessary? PS. It works on my local MS SQL Server 2012 (copy data and schema from Azure). But does not work with SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` is being translated into:

```
convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [dateTimeServer], 102) ,  102)
```

This is causing your query to be [non-sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), resulting in slow performance and timeout. I recommend making the following changes

---

First off, I do not see why you need to truncate the time in your `where` clause. I suggest you make this change:

```
where i.dateTimeServer.Value >= startDate && i.dateTimeServer.Value <= endDate
```

This will prevent the database from having to run the function on every record.

---

If the query still times out, I would change the `group by` to:

```
group i by new { 
   i.dateTimeServer.Value.Year, 
   i.dateTimeServer.Value.Month, 
   i.dateTimeServer.Value.Day 
}
```

Functionally this is the same, but I believe it produces a more friendly translation:

```
DATEPART (year, dateTimeServer), DATEPART (month, dateTimeServer) etc..
```

---

Add an index to `dateTimeServer`

---

If all else fails, you will need to add a column to your table with the time portion truncated. Index it and use it in your query.

Comment: How to create this index? As I understand, I should create an index without time? I try to create, but no ability to truncate time http://www.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/6u64wnWw3kQ.html

Comment: @OlegSh - You can't create an index without time. Is the query still timing out when you create the `dateTimeServer` index?

Comment: you write me "Add an index to dateTimeServer". What sense in index with time ?

Comment: @OlegSh - It will be used in your `where` clause to filter down the data range

Comment: right now DB processor does not filter by data range?

Comment: @OlegSh - The database will have to read every record in order to get the `dateTimeServer`. If you have an index on the column, it will be able to read the index, and therefore execute faster